# how to add suffix url wordpress example (/post-name/images)

Tags: wordpress

I want to show post images into a separated page for example blow URL:

**/post-name/images**

At the moment this URL returns a 404 page.

how to show my images in this URL?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a [`get_attached_media()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/) function as Version 3.6, that returns an associative array of all of the images attached to a post.

After that, there are a couple of ways to add the `/images` path to the URL.

- You can use the [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter
  to check the current URL, unset the `is_404` boolean, and pass in a PHP Template.
- You can make use of [This WPSE Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress) to add `/images` as a "virtual page" using `.htaccess` and/or [`WP::parse_request()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/parse_request/) rules, and load in a PHP template that way
- You could instead use query parameters `/post-name/?images=true` and check for that in your `single.php` (or equivalent file), and use [`get_attached_media()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/)
- You could instead use query parameters `/post-name/?images=true` and make use of the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter in your `functions.php` file, and return the [`get_attached_media()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/) instead of the content

Comment: I use the first way, but there is a problem, I lose **post_id** in `$wp_query` to get the gallery

Comment: If you use the first method without handling the request with `WP::parse_request()` or `.htaccess`, you'll need to parse the URL and use the [`url_to_postid()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/) function to get the ID back, since the request isn't to an actual permalink.